# Database reverse engineering tool with columnDefinition support

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, reverse-engineering

I am trying to generate entities from a MSSQL database. I tried in eclipse and intellij idea with the built in tools for entities generation from database but I am having some issues with the generated entities.

char, nvarchar fields are mapped as string and the @Column annotation doesn't contain the columnDefinition (e.g. columnDefinition = "char") property. 
This results in a HibernateException when the validation occurs:
HibernateException: Wrong column type in  for column . Found: char, expected: nvarchar.

Is there a tool that adds this property in @Column annotations? The database has over 1000 tables and that is why I cant do this "by hand".

Thanks for any help/hint.

Comment: What dialect is Hibernate using?

Comment: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect. I have also tried with SQLServer2005Dialect and SQLServer2012Dialect